# ActiveRecord query on model methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I have the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :location, :address

  attr_internal_accessor :user_address

  def user_address
    self.address
  end

end

class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :title, :description, :tags
  delegate :address, :to => :user, :prefix => true

end
```

When I try to do this in AR this is what the call looks like:

```
Problem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "problems".* FROM "problems" ORDER BY problems.user_address asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: problems.user_address: SELECT  "problems".* FROM "problems" ORDER BY problems.user_address asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 173ms
```

It gives me an error that it is not a column which is true, however it generates data just like active record would.

How can I search the output if this function as if it was a native active record column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i usually do this is by using the model you want to return.

So if its addresses you want, something like:

```
def user_address
  Address.joins(:users).where(:user_id => user.id)
end
```

This way you get an AR relation object back and you can chain them.

Comment: yeah its already delegated to the user record. And I can already call the method like that. I cant access it as an active record column though when searching and sorting.

Comment: oh, i see, i miss-understood your question.

Comment: Ok, i edited my answer with my new understanding of your question. :)

Comment: Address is a record under the user model. There is no separate model for Addresses. I just want the user object to return the address as a string and for that to be sort-able. Is there no way to fake a attribute?

Comment: NP, sorry i'm not helping much... Perhaps you could edit your question to include some code as you would like to see it work.  That might help in clarifying your intent.

Answer (score 1):

The method `user_address` is supposed to be used in the code (mostly views), not to be passed to AR.

AR would require things to be more understood by the DB.

To DB sort (order) using the User#address column:

```
#Rails 3
p = Problem.includes(:user).order("users.address ASC").first
p.user_address

#Rails 2
p = Problem.find(:first, :include => :user, :order => "users.address ASC")
p.user_address
```

It might also be wise to check if a user exist for a problem when

```
def user_address
  self.user.try(:address) #just in case a problem doesn't have an associated user
end
```